# Text overflow: is there a way to not set a fixed width for the parent?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show a list of elements, which have a picture, a title and some additional information in Flutter. My layout is supposed to look like this:

[image: desired layout]

I have implemented this using a `ListView` with `Card` children. I then use a `Row` to have the image on the left and the info on the right. Then I use a `Column` to have my title on top and the rest of the info below.

My problem is with the title, which may be too large for width of its container. What I originally thought was letting the user scroll through the text, but I'm not sure if it is possible to nest two scrolling-enabled widgets in Flutter, so I settled with using `TextOverflow.ellipsis`. However in my basic setup `TextOverflow.ellipsis` has no effect, and instead I face an overflow error.

After looking this up online I figured that I had to put my `Text` into an `Expanded` or `Flexible`, which themselves had to be a direct child of a `Flex` (I used `Row`). However this wasn't enough still, as I got the following error: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.`. To fix this I had to add a `Container` as parent of my `Row` (`Flex`) with a fixed width.

Here is my current code:

```
Card(
  color: backgroundColor,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      MyImageWidget(),
      Container(
        height: 60,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 12),
              height: 30,
              width: 340, // I don't want this
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      "Title which may be long, very very long",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Is there a way to get rid of this fixed width constraint? I know that I could use Media Queries but I don't want to do this unless I absolutely have to, because I might change the padding of several elements, or even move to a grid view on larger screens.

Or if I absolutely have to set this fixed width, is there a way I could ask Flutter to find out what the width of my `Container` would be if it had no content, and then apply it as fixed width of itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap your right-side `Column` inside an `Expanded` widget to let it take all the remaining available space inside the `Row` and the `TextOverflow.ellipsis` will take care of the rest.

```dart
return Card(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          MyImageWidget(),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 4,
                horizontal: 12,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Title which may very very very very very very",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```